# Laravel Migrations Deleted File

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm working through Laracasts Laravel 5 Fundamentals however when coming to run a migration again I found that I had duplicate migrations at which point I figured - I should likely delete that. So I did... then began my issues.

When I attempt to load a migration now I get the following error:

`[ErrorException]
  include(/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/database/migrations/2015_05_24_211527_create_articles_table.php): failed to
   open stream: No such file or directory`

However when I checked my database (Note that I have deleted and recreated it in order to combat my issue) and there are only two records in the mirgations table:

`vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Laravel$ sqlite3 storage/database.sqlite
SQLite version 3.8.6 2014-08-15 11:46:33
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select * from migrations;
2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table|1
2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table|1
sqlite>`

Any help would be appreciated, if I'm being a moron and missing something obvious please feel free to point that out too.

Thanks!

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first error:

```
[ErrorException]
  include(/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/database/migrations/2015_05_24_211527_create_articles_table.php): failed to
   open stream: No such file or directory
```

should be fixed executing `composer dump-autoload`.

About the second one: *"However when I checked my database (Note that I have deleted and recreated it in order to combat my issue) and there are only two records in the mirgations table:"*

As you said that you have recreated it, something went wrong because there is no *migrations* table, delete it and build it again

```
rm storage/database.sqlite
touch storage/database.sqlite
php artisan migrate:install
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Seemed to work, I have another issue now but I'll try to tackle that myself. Thanks!

Comment: @marcanuy Worked for me with the same issue, just wondering why that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Please try, this one helped me to solve my problem

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Thanks